# psql clean/reset database to just schema

Tags: postgresql, psql

I did an import to my database, but it came with content. I want to reset the database to just the schema. Meaning all content from tables dropped, but schema of tables left. And autoincrementing fields are reset to start from the beginning.

Is this possible with psql? I'm seeing commands that are dropping content with specific table commands, I just want a generic `psql reset-to-schema`.

Comment: Export your database to DDL only (depending on what you use to connect to the db). Remove the inserts for the data and change the sequence numbers by hand.

Comment: @BlueIris Is there any command to empty all tables and reset autoincrementers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a dump of your database (using `pg_dump`), drop and recreate the database (you now have an empty database) and restore all schema data (using `pg_restore` with option `--schema-only`). This will just restore the data definitions (tables, types, sequences, functions etc.) but not the data itself.

For more options, have a look at the manual. You might use these lines if all PG environment variables are set up as needed, otherwise you will at least need to specify some connection information:

```sh
pg_dump -F c -f <dump_file_name_here> <db_name_here>
pg_restore -c -C -F c -d <db_name_here> --schema-only <dump_file_name_here>
```

It is also possible to put the option `--schema-only` to the `pg_dump`. If you do not want to use the data anymore, this might give a huge speedup.

Comment: Thanks may you please make it a complete solution so I can accept, ie if it was simply: `pg_dump && pg_restore --schema-only` (I know its not but for completeness).

Comment: There you go, eventhough it is not tested in any way. Tbh, reading the manual sometimes is good practice as well. Find it here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: Thanks those links will help readers of this answer how to read the docs. Thank you very much. Learning the docs is like 80% of the battle.